# Boost Spirit auto-rule problem

Tags: boost, attributes, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, propagation

I'm using attribute propagation to construct a syntax tree for a toy language. I've hit a problem at the definition of my if statement, it's hard to tell from the error message but I think the rhs attribute isn't collapsing into the expected attribute. It should collapse to a `tuple <double,Statement,optional<Statement>>` I think.

The error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\boost_1_43_0\boost\variant\variant.hpp|1293|error: no matching function for call to 'boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::initializer_root, mpl_::int_<0> >, boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list3<boost::recursive_wrapper<Lang::CompoundStatement>, boost::recursive_wrapper<Lang::IfStatement>, Lang::VarStatement> > >::initializer_node, mpl_::int_<1> >, boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list2<boost::recursive_wrapper<Lang::IfStatemen [error cuts out here]`

Thanks.

P.S.
I couldn't get the code to display right, there's a plaintext version here: http://freetexthost.com/a3smzx0zk5

P.P.S. 
Some information I forogt to mention.
It works if I remove `"else" >>` and change `> statement` to `>> statement`, but `"else" >> statement` should collapse to just statement. Explicitly creating "else" as a qi::lit doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

The sequence `operator>>()` and the expectation `operator>()` do not mix well in terms of attribute handling. If you use both operators in the same expression the overall attribute does not get flattened. That would happen if you were using the one or the other only.

For this reason the attribute exposed by the expression:

```
if_statement %= "if" > qi::double_ > statement >> -("else" > statement) ;
```

is:

```
tuple <tuple <double, Statement>, optional<Statement> >
```

which explains your compilation problems. Rewriting the epression as:

```
if_statement %= "if" > qi::double_ > statement > -("else" > statement) ;
```

should solve the issue, though (without changing the semantics).

Comment: Good thought but it's still not working. Works if I remove the else, that's the only clue I have.

Comment: Ok, then I would like to see a small self-contained test I can compile. Otherwise it's almost impossible to tell what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, seems like I can't edit or comment, so I'll have to post this as an answer.

I got around the problem by splitting the rule into an if statement rule and an if-else statement rule. However, the problem is back for my definition of an init declaration.
`init_decl
        %=  identifier
            >> -('=' >> expression)
        ;`

`identifier
        %=  lexeme[(alpha | char_(''))
                    >> *(alnum | char('_'))]
        ;`

`expression
        %=  literal
        ;`

`literal
        %=  real_literal
        |   string_literal
        ;`

`real_literal
        %=  double_
        ;`

`string_literal
        %=  lexeme['"'
            >> *(char_ - '"')
            >> '"']
        ;`

Same problem as before. However, I didn't do a good job of investigation the problem the first time at all.

`In member function 'void boost::variant::convert_construct(T&, int, mpl_::false_) [with T = const Lang::Elements::Expression, T0_ = double, T1 = std::basic_string, std::allocator >, T2 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T3 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T4 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T5 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T6 = boost::detail::variant::void_, T7 = boost::detail::vari`

That is this method:

`template <typename T>`

```
void convert_construct(
      T& operand
    , int
    , mpl::false_ = mpl::false_() // is_foreign_variant
    )
{
    // NOTE TO USER :
    // Compile error here indicates that the given type is not 
    // unambiguously convertible to one of the variant's types
    // (or that no conversion exists).
    //
    indicate_which(
          initializer::initialize(
              storage_.address()
            , operand
            )
        );
}</code>
```

Remember this error originates from the %= in the init_decl expression. The only variant in this expression is the one contained by the Expression object which is the expression rule's attribute value. The error seems to say that a variant (the type of object Expression contains) is trying to instantiate itself from an Expression, but I can't see this anywhere in the code. Anyway, I added cast operators to the Expression struct that exposes its underlying variant, but still I got the error.

The method that calls the method above is this:

`template <typename T>`

```
variant(const T& operand)
{
    convert_construct(operand, 1L);
}</code>
```

It seems like it's trying to call this method instead:

template <typename Variant>

```
void convert_construct(
      Variant& operand
    , long
    , mpl::true_// is_foreign_variant
    )
{
    convert_copy_into visitor(storage_.address());
    indicate_which(
          operand.internal_apply_visitor(visitor)
        );
}</code>
```

Is this a compiler misunderstanding that is the cause of this error?